# Doesn't display the object in view/html angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm learning MEAN , i'm trying to display information from object, it has 2 arrays, it semms is working because I can see the object with console log of Javascript but it doesn't showing in html.

My code from javascript (books.js)

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
  console.log("BooksController loaded");

  $scope.getBooks = function(){
    $http.get('/api/books')
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response)
      $scope.books = response;
    });
  }

}]);
```

My code from html (book.html)

```
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getBooks()">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Latest Books</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="book in books">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="col-md-6">

            {{book.title}}
            <p>
              {{book.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="{{book.image_url}}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image of getting data with console

[Screenshot of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Exz1.png)

Question is I can't figure out how to solve it, because it doesn't display in book.html.

[Screenshot of book.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mpdH.png)

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: any errors in the console? please post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the assignment of the response - it should be:

```
$scope.books = response.data;
```

Notice how in your console you have to expand `data` to see your array - because your response is an object, containing `data` as a key with your array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it the value of response.data

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

    myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
    console.log("BooksController loaded");
    $scope.books = '';
    $scope.getBooks = function(){
     $http.get('/api/books')
     .then(function(response){
      console.log(response)
      $scope.books = response.data;
    });
  }

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and reply.